# Strip Executable (Windows)

Tags: executable, strip

I've heard that strip is a program that makes an executable smaller.

I've tried to turn it on from my compiler (for Python) but when it comes to run strip I just see "strip is not recognized as a command or as a program" error from the Command Prompt.

So where do I get the executable of strip for Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strip is part of [GNU's binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/).

Comment: Yes but that's for linux, isn't it?

Comment: You can get strip from Cygwin, and that strip works on Windows PE executables too!

Answer (score 3):

Strip removes information such as debugging symbols from object files. Doing this makes the file smaller.

If you have it, it would likely be distributed with your C compiler (such as GCC).

Comment: The executables pyInstaller (the compiler I'm using) makes 6 MB executables even out of the smallest program.. that's why I'd like to make it weight less. I've already tried UPX but didn't make it so light.

Comment: @terabytest see link in my answer to the StripReloc site - using exe compressors can have some very annoying side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Unix/Linux style strip will remove symbol info that is used for debugging purposes.  AFAIK under Windows a strip utility is specific to the compiler that was used.  See [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413171/what-is-strip-gcc-application-used-for) for more info.

A related utility that might be useful is [StripReloc](http://www.jrsoftware.org/striprlc.php), a utility that removes relocation info from executables and as such makes them smaller.  Read the instructions though, it's not recommended to run it blindly against every .exe on your system...