# How to find the code that blows up the size of my application?

Tags: c++, windows, size

I have a C++ Windows application that uses STL, boost and several other libs.
Application does not do much but have a big size.
I have to find a way to reduce the size of the app, but I do not understand which part of these libraries blows up the size of my app.

(Maybe I can switch STL/boost, or implement smth by myself, or do smth by a different way, etc...)

Does we have any tools/guides to investigate imported symbols and find out which give biggest increment to the size of the app?

UPDATE

I'm asking about release build.

I do not ask about configuration of compiler, but I ask about the tool that will tell what parts of my code give the biggest increase of the size of my app.

All libs included statically. Therefore if I could remove heavy-weight dependencies size of the app will be significantly smaller.

Comment: On Unix, `nm` is a useful tool https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix)

Comment: @ChrisBeck Thank you. I'll try `nm` if I do not find smth for Windows...

Comment: Boost might be big: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839172/why-my-c-output-executable-is-so-big

Comment: Are .lib files that the app link against large? If yes, and you need those libs, then not much can be done about the size. Why is size important?

Comment: @Dialecticus But if I knew which lib gives huge increase of the size of the app I could try to remove that dependency...

Comment: In Visual Studio you can use [/VERBOSE:LIB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) to see that.

Comment: I know about that flag. But with this flag I do not know list of the methods imported from the lib. And I do not know size of the methods...

Comment: Remove that .lib from the list and then the linker will complain about the missing functions.

Comment: Have the linker generate a map file ([/MAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7xkk3e2.aspx)).

Comment: Size of the methods (functions even) are not important. As far as I know the whole lib is included, so you have to replace all the functions to remove the lib from the picture.

Comment: @Dialecticus: Templated code is not imported from a LIB.

Comment: You might be able to reduce the size by using global optimization. I haven't tried that though. But it stands to reason: knowledge about the complete program is needed in order to eliminate dead code.

Answer (score 1):

Boost is big library. If you need Boost you do not need STL.

If STL is enough for your needs then you can use just STL.

Also, I think you can configure Visual Studio to print to the output the trace of the linking process.

Some ideas for inspecting libs are here:

[How to See the Contents of Windows library (*.lib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305287/how-to-see-the-contents-of-windows-library-lib)

[Tools for inspecting .lib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488809/tools-for-inspecting-lib-files)

Comment: Ok. For example I need boost.thread. I can use flag `/VERBOSE:LIB` and see that my app linked against this lib. But I do not know list of the methods imported from the lib. And I do not know size of the methods...

Comment: @VictorMezrin I added some  possibly helpful links from stackoverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Are you looking at debug build? That might be bigger. What about doing `strip` on the executable?

Comment: No, I'm asking about release build

Comment: How about strip, does that help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540523/strip-executable ?

Comment: `Strip` removes symbol info that is used for debugging purposes. On Windows (VS2015) debugging info not placed in the release build.