# how to merge stripped symbols with binary?

Tags: gcc, merge, debugging, symbols, pdb-files

I compiled the Qt Framework with debugging enabled, but the script stripped the debugging symbols from the libraries and saved them as *.debug files -- just like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866721/how-to-generate-gcc-debug-symbol-outside-the-build-target).
Sadly I need these symbols *inside* the .so files, so I can continue working with them. There seems no way to teach my debugger to load external (non-PDB) symbols. So another way of solving my problem might be converting the .debug files to PDB format, which might also be a problem.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What was the script you were using? Can you show the code for the script. Maybe the line in there references 'strip'...

Comment: Have a look here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413171/what-is-strip-gcc-application-used-for