# Reducing GCC target EXE code size?

Tags: gcc, size, executable, llvm

When I compiled a no-op program:

```
int main(void)
{
    return 0;
}
```

with various compilers:

- GCC (similar result to LLVM as well): Gave a 10-KiB executable (compiled with `-s`)

  - Sections: `.CRT`, `.bss`, `.data`, `.idata`, `.rdata`, `.text`, `.tls`
  - Depends on `msvcrt.dll` and `kernel32.dll`
- MSVC 2010: Gave a 5.5 KiB executable (compiled with `/MD /Ox`)

  - Sections: `.data`, `.rdata`, `.reloc`, `.text`
  - Depends on `msvcr100.dll` and `kernel32.dll`
  - Could have been further reduced by merging `.rdata` with `.text`
- Windows Driver Kit 7.1: Gave a 6.5 KiB executable (compiled with `/MD /Ox`, linked with `msvcrt_winxp.obj` to allow it to run on XP)

  - Sections: `.data`, `.rdata`, `.text`
  - Depends on `msvcrt.dll` and `kernel32.dll`
  - Could have been further reduced by merging `.rdata` with `.text`
- Windows 2003 Driver Development Kit: Gave a 3.5 KiB executable

  - Sections: `.data`, `.rdata`, `.text`
  - Depends on `msvcrt.dll`
  - Could have been further reduced by merging `.rdata` with `.text`
- Tiny C Compiler (TCC): Gave a 1.5 KiB executable

  - Sections: `.data`, `.text`
  - Depends on `msvcrt.dll`

So I guess the question is simple:

Is it possible to further reduce GCC or LLVM's target executable sizes so that they are closer to the bare-minimum possible, while still linking to `msvcrt.dll`?

(Edit: I'm obviously not looking for packers like `UPX`, etc.)

Comment: Could you explain why are you asking? Do you often compile such a tiny program? Isn't it more important for a compiler to compile well realistic programs?? (most of them are much bigger)!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413171/what-is-strip-gcc-application-used-for, http://embeddedfreak.wordpress.com/2009/02/10/removing-unused-functionsdead-codes-with-gccgnu-ld/

Comment: @Ulterior: The `-s` option is pretty much the same as `strip`. The other options also didn't help.

Comment: On Linux/x86-64/Debian/Sid with `gcc-4.6 -O2 -flto -s nop.c -o nop` I am getting a `nop` file of 4408 bytes, and of 4392 bytes when compiled with `gcc-4.6 -Os -flto -s nop.c -o nop`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Part of it is being paranoid, part of it is actually a practical issue: I often send Base64 versions of executables around, and it's a LOT handier to send a Base64 version of a 1-KiB executable than a 10-KiB executable when you're pasting it within e.g. a message.

Comment: Don't you send programs with several hundred lines of source code at least?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a particularly meaningful thing to do. It might be possible to eliminate a few things, but as soon as you have a program that actually does anything then it'll pull those things straight back in again.

For example, on another platform (I don't do much Windows stuff), the minimum size for a program is larger than you would think because every program has an atexit handler to clean up. That handler has a possible error case which means it pull in printf and all the I/O stuff. Atexit itself also pulls in malloc and all the memory handing stuff. And no doubt there's a few other bits besides. The end result is a 400KB static binary size. That's annoying in a no-op program, but in reality all programs would need this stuff, so it's a moot point.

In general, if you want to minimise program size, compile with `-Os`, and try to use `-flto` *or* `-fwhole-program` (but this last will need lots of changes to your build procedure). Also, don't use `-g`, and do strip the final binaries (if that doesn't break them).