# Hide specific exported symbol with gcc

Tags: gcc, hide, symbols, stripping

I need to hide a specific exported symbol.
Which is "___udivdi3"
But i don't know how.

I have a script the strip symbols after the build.
Then i have to pass the binary into a third party tool (wrapper)that complain about this exported symbol.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look a this discussion: [What is the difference between "gcc -s" and a "strip" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349166/gcc-s-and-bash-command-strip)
Try `strip -N ___udivdi3 objfile`.