# Does removing relocation data using `-s` affect a position dependent executable

Tags: c++, gcc, executable, relocation, aslr

I need to know if using **-s** in GCC (g++) will have any effects on the PIE. I also want to know its effects on a position-dependent executable. As far as I know, not using any linking option (like **-pie** and **-fpie**) results in a non-PIE just like when using **-no-pie**. Now I have an executable and that's probably non-PIE since I have not specified **-pie** in the link command. Can `-s` cause any problems? Will it improve the performance (since the exe will be smaller)?

I also checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14175040/effects-of-removing-all-symbol-table-and-relocation-information-from-an-executab) and in the answer it says:

> It seems pretty clear that removing relocation information would interfere with ASLR.

But ASLR only deals with position-independent executables, right? Could removing relocation data from a *position-dependent executable* interfere with ASLR?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a bit of research, I found some info that might be correct.

From [GCC Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options):

> -pie
>
> Produce a dynamically linked position independent executable on targets that support it.
>
> -no-pie
>
> Don’t produce a dynamically linked position independent executable.

Looking at this, my guess is that both options produce *position-independent executable* and the only difference is that the former is *dynamically linked* but the latter is not *dynamically linked* (statically linked??). Therefore in both cases, the executable contains relocation data. However, it is still unclear to me whether the generated executable (using `-s`) interferes with ASLR or not.