# why is binary compiled with gcc not stripped by default

Tags: c, gcc

When I compile my program `gcc -o myprog myprog.c`, the produced binary is not stripped:

```
myprog: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically 
linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.26, 
BuildID[sha1]=0x2697ed96b65e8a11239af0a44abc7896954b6e20, not stripped
```

I am wondering why `gcc` produces non-stripped binaries by default, when I did not provide any debuging parameter.

Should all binaries be stripped after being compiled, i.e. using `strip myprog`? Or is there an advantage of having a binary non-stripped?

AFAICS, most binaries in `/bin/`, `/usr/bin/` are stripped.

Comment: AFAIK on Linux stripping is usually done via `install` command

Comment: @Anycorn - in which situation would I use the `install` command? I have never heard about it up until now.

Comment: `install` is usually used to move files from build directory into its final destination, `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, etc.  It has options to strip binary, set permissions, etc: http://linux.die.net/man/1/install

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349166/gcc-s-and-bash-command-strip). Symbols that gcc doesn't strip by default are not debugging information, they are relocation information (something that is needed for linking).

Comment: No need to strip them. IIUC: the loader ignores them, VM is you friend, and diskspace is for free.

Comment: Very valid concern and we usually assume that GCC would strip this information by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK Once the binary is stripped you wont be able to get the stripped information back until or unless you regenerate the binary. stripping is useful when you have memory constraints to look after. This might be the reason strip is not enabled by default in GCC.

Comment: OK, but almost all binaries on my linux system are stripped. So why does gcc leave the extra symbols?

Comment: As you already knowing strip is useful to save space after a program has been debugged and to limit dynamically bound symbols. You may want to debug your program for possible errors.

Comment: The extra symbol is useful while debugging the program.