# Unable to remove symbolic names from executable created with Cmake

Tags: c++, unix, cmake, obfuscation

I have the following files

```
main.cpp:
#include "f.h"

int main(){
    f();
}

f.h:
int f();

f.cpp:
int f(){
    int x=1;
}
```

First I am compiling `f.cpp` to an object file: `gcc -c f.cpp -O0`
and use this object file to compile `main.cpp` `gcc f.o main.cpp`.

Performing `gdb a.out`, `info functions` shows `f()`. Executing `strip a.out` removes it.

I would like to do the same thing using Cmake. I have created the following directory structure with main directories `f` and `main`:

```
f
    build
    src
        f.h
        f.c
        CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(f)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O0")
add_library(f OBJECT
    f.cpp
)

main
    build
    src
        main.cpp
        CMakeLists.txt

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.8)
project(main)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../f/src
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../f/build)
add_executable(main
    main.cpp
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:f>
)
```

I ran `cmake` and `make` first in `f`, after that in `main`. I have got the `main` executable with `f()`. However issuing `strip main`, or even `strip -s main` does not remove the symbolic name `f()`.

1. Why does not remove `strip` the symbolic names if I use Cmake?
2. Is there a way to compile my files in the same way (object file from f.cpp and after that main executable) using Cmake, and remove symbolic names from the executable?

Comment: C or C++? You tagged this C yet those files are apparently C++ files.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used strip, but according to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strip_(Unix)) you can achieve the same effect with the `-s` compiler option. You could try adding `-s` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE`. It appears they may not be [entirely equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349166/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-s-and-a-strip-command) though.