# How to suppress function names in disassembled output?

Tags: c, assembly, disassembly, objdump

When creating the disassembly output of an `obj` or an `exe` file, `objdump` creates function names in angle brackets, like;

```
0000000000000598 <SomeFunctionName>:
 598:   push   rbp
 599:   push   rbx
 59a:   sub    rsp,0x38
 59e:   lea    rbp,[rsp+0x80]
...
...
...
0000000000000878 <main>:
...
 8a3:   lea    rax,[rbp-0x10]
 8a7:   mov    r8,rax
 8aa:   mov    edx,0x3
 8af:   mov    ecx,0x3
 8b4:   call   598 <SomeFunctionName>   ; <- here
 8b9:   test   eax,eax
 8bb:   jne    8d5 <main+0x5d>          ; <- here as well
...
```

I'm aware that those string literals show branching in the program flow (line numbers to jump to). But, as the line number is already shown (as `598` in `SomeFunctionName`), is there a **directive** for `objdump` to suppress those string literals in the angle brackets (of course, the absolute address `598` would still remain)?

Comment: If you want to remove that from the *output*, you can use any text processing tool (python, awk, sed, etc.). But why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can [`strip`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip) executables, libraries, ...

Comment: Alo see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349166/what-is-the-difference-between-gcc-s-and-a-strip-command

Comment: The phrase you're looking for is "symbol name".  (Also, terminology nitpick: I'm not sure "string literal" fits perfectly.  This isn't source code; it doesn't turn into string data when compiled.)

Comment: @PeterCordes : You're right, that phrase got to be "symbol name."

Comment: @pmg : The `-s` directive with `gcc` worked. I used it in *compile* phase and it didn't work but when I pulled the `-s` directive into *linking* phase, it did the trick! Thanks.